# How to send images in Twilio chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I want to add the capability of sending images in chat built using twilio chat SDK ,
I wonder how to display the image uploaded from my device in the chat ?

I tried to see if this can be done using the message media attribute , but I endup accessing 4 fields

1. contentType
2. fileName
3. SID => i don't know what is that
4. size

can anyone help to explain how to do what I want ?